# How do I add a multidimensional array (AoA) to Excel using Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

I want to add my data stored in 2x2 dimension array in Excel using Perl. I know how to open and add simple data. This I can do using for loop. But how can I do it elegantly?

This is what I am trying to do

```
$sheet->Range("A1:B"."$size")->{Value} = @$data;
                                         or   @data;
                                         or   {@data};
                                         or   {\@data};
```

where `@data` is two dimensional array.

```
# use existing instance if Excel is already running
eval {$ex = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')};
die "Excel not installed" if $@;
unless (defined $ex) {
    $ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
            or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
}


# get a new workbook
$book = $ex->Workbooks->Add;

# write to a particular cell
$sheet = $book->Worksheets(1);
print "A1:B"."$size";
# write a 2 rows by 3 columns range

$sheet->Range("A1:B"."$size")->{Value} = @$data;
```

Comment: please don't ask (mostly) unrelated questions together

Comment: Alnitak is completely right. Please make the question about Paint a separate one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you  are using Win32::OLE but this sort of thing is also quite easy with [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('test.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Get your AoA from somewhere.
my $data = [
    [ 'Hello', 'world', 123   ],
    [ 'Bye',   'bye',   4.567 ],
];

# Write the data.
$worksheet->write_col( 'A1', $data );
```

Comment: The downside to Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is that you can't modify an existing spreadsheet. This means you must use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel to copy the data from an existing spreadsheet into the one you want modified, then modify it. The code gets ugly, so Win32::OLE can be better if you are on Win32.

Comment: The upside of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is that it is fast, well documented and works on every platform that Perl works on. Its function, which I would hope is explicit, is to create a new Excel file. To modify an existing Excel file there is Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Saveparser.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen that module before; I will have to go check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some reading (I don't have a Win32 box in front of me), it looks like the `Value` attribute of `Range` handles a reference to an [AoA](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS) correctly, so try saying:

```
my $data = [
    ["a1", "b1"],
    ["a2", "b2"],
];
$sheet->Range("A1:B" . @$data)->{Value} = $data;
```

Comment: Range.Value is an array of arrays (object[,] in C# notation) size of Rows * Columns (so called R1C1 notation). In your example, 2*2. For A1:C4 size will be 4*3

Comment: In other words, there is no need for $size. Basing on the size of $data, it always must be 2.

Comment: I just copied the example without thinking, I have corrected it to use the AoA to determine the number of rows.